# Как разрешить CORS в django только для определенного адреса?

Tags: django, api, cors

Нашел примеры как разрешить полностью cors с помощью django-cors-headers

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Но я хочу разрешить полный доступ только к одному api, а в остальном к сайту запретить.

Подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CORS](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol) - это инструмент ограничения доступа к ресурсам на *домене*. В соответствии с этим, вам следует разделить приложение на Django на n-субдоменов/-серверов. Пример:

- *example.com*
- *api.example.com*
- *private.example.com*

Тогда вы сможете разрешить wildcard (*) доступ для домена *api.example.com* и ограничить использование *private.example.com* любым удобным вам способом. Например, с помощью django-cors-headers (как [указано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1363042/197719) в одном из ответов), с помощью wsgi-/asgi- middleware, или настроек реверс-прокси/балансировщика (пример для [nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36649003/5644331)).

Вы **не сможете** покрыть *только часть эндпоинтов* на **едином домене**, т.к. ограничения применимы только к домену.

Answer (score 2):

Список источников, авторизованных для выполнения межсайтовых HTTP-запросов задается с помощью параметра `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://example.com",
    "https://sub.example.com",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
]
```

https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#configuration